# Understanding Cublas: vector addition (asum)

Tags: cuda, cublas

According to [CUBLAS reference](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#topic_6_3), asum function (for getting the sum of the elements of a vector) is:

```
cublasStatus_t  cublasSasum(cublasHandle_t handle, int n, const float *x, int incx, float *result)
```

You can see in the link to the reference the parameters explanation, roughly we have a vector `x` of `n` elements with `incx` distance between elements.

My code is (quite simplified, but I also tested this one and there is still the error):

```
int arraySize = 10;
float* a = (float*) malloc (sizeof(float) * arraySize);

float* d_a;
cudaMalloc((void**) &d_a, sizeof(float) * arraySize);

for (int i=0; i<arraySize; i++)
    a[i]=0.8f;

cudaMemcpy(d_a, a, sizeof(float) * arraySize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

cublasStatus_t ret;  
cublasHandle_t handle;
ret = cublasCreate(&handle);

float* cb_result = (float*) malloc (sizeof(float));

ret = cublasSasum(handle, arraySize, d_a, sizeof(float), cb_result);

printf("\n\nCUBLAS: %.3f", *cb_result);

cublasDestroy(handle);
```

I have removed error checking for simplifying the code (there are no errors, CUBLAS functions return `CUDA_STATUS_SUCCESS`) and `free` and `cudaFree`.

It compiles, it runs, it doesn't throw any error, but result printed is `0`, and, debugging, it is actually `1.QNAN`.

What did i miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the arguments to `cublasSasum` is incorrect. The call should look like this:

```
ret = cublasSasum(handle, arraySize, d_a, 1, cb_result);
```

Note that the second last argument, `incx`, should be in *words*, not *bytes*.

Comment: The argument `incx` is in **elements**, not in bytes or words.

Comment: @shinjin: words and elements are tl the same in this case.  An element is a 32 bit word.

Comment: @talonmies: you are right, but that's only true for floats, and it's just a consequence of how `incx` is defined. It make more sense to think about `incx` in elements, so it always means the same, even for single/double real/complex vectors. Not to mention, that the size of a word on 64 bit systems is 64 bits.